What is the glyph in hangul for the open-mid front unrounded vowel (The "EH" sound in the English "echo" and English "Elk")?
What is the glyph in hangul for the open-mid front un-rounded vowel ?
The open-mid front un-rounded vowel is the same as the "EH" sound in the English language.
There is an "EH" sound at the beginning of the English word for "echo" and the English word for "Elk"

English /ɛ/ is transliterated as ㅔ, eg 아웃렛 /autlɛt/ "outlet" or 펠리컨 /pɛlikən/ "pelican".
I think there are official transliteration rules for converting from the English IPA transcription as one would find in a pronunciation dictionary.
